# How to make a camera move in the direction it is facing in java?

Tags: java, camera, rotation, direction

I need a way(in java) to calculate which direction my camera will move forward on the x and z axes based on the direction my camera is facing(yaw), and for y(the vertical axis), the pitch. I'm making my own game engine and my own camera.

With all values defaulting at zero, moving the camera correctly directs all movement along the positive z axis. However, when I pan the camera to the left or right(thereby changing the yaw), the camera still only moves along the z axis... So how do I calculate the change in direction to the x, y, and z axes?

The value range on the yaw is 0(south), 45(southwest), 90(west), 135(northwest), 180(north), 225(northeast), 270(east), 315(southeast), and back to 360(south, same as 0).

What I'm looking for with the compass directions(where a '+' or '-' indicates a change in value along that axis):

```
South = x, y, z+
SouthWest = x+, y, z+
West = x+, y, z
NorthWest = x+, y, z-
North = x, y, z-
NorthEast = x-, y, z-
East = x-, y, z
SouthEast = x-, y, z+
```

The value range on the pitch is 0.0(middle), 100.0(up all the way), and -100.0(down all the way).

If I need to post some code, I can, but it might get complicated. I hope I'm making some kind of sense so that someone can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to move the camera in direction *y* with distance *k*.
For the sake of simplicity, i will convert your directions to angles, where 0.0 represents right, Pi/2 represents up, Pi represents left, 3*Pi/2 represents down and so.

EDIT: As you say y of camera will be affected only by the pitch.  X and z, instead will be affected by both the yaw and the pitch.

You can calculate the new x, y and z by the following:

```
float y = // Yaw angle
float p = // Pitch angle
float k = // Move distance

float xzLength = cos(p) * k;
float dx = xzLength * cos(y);
float dz = xzLength * sin(y);
float dy = k * sin(p);

// Update your camera:
camera.x += dx;
camera.y += dy;
camera.z += dz;
```

Obviously, yaw and pitch do not change, so you don't need to update them.

Comment: Great, I'll look into that as soon as I can! Just one quick question, if I did in fact want pitch(up and down movement) to be factored into the x and z values for a 'flying' camera, how would I do this?

Comment: I think that pitch is actually factored into x and z in my solution, as you can see xzLength depends on p and dz, dx depend on it, am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Contrarily, if you want *not* to factor the pitch in x and z, you should let just xzLength = k instead

Comment: Sorry, it was an error in my statements that made you believe that x and z were affected only by the yaw, edited!

Comment: When you say angle, do you mean like the 0 - 360 kind, or is it a different value of numbers? I ask this because I converted my rotation(yaw) and the up and down(pitch) values to return angle values, but your methods only sort of work. As I pan the camera more, in turn adding to the rotation(yaw) and turning the camera right, the camera starts moving to the left and backwards and sometimes to the right. I really hope it's an error on my part, but maybe you can find something wrong. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: If you use trigonometric functions, you have to use angles in the range or 0.0 - 2*Pi (Pi=3.1429....).  There could be an error in my logic too, i'm gonna check it again ^^

Comment: Okay, cool. I'll go look over my code as well, while you do that!

Comment: Oh, one thing, if you use trigonometric functions, the right is represented by angle 0.0, then going counter-clockwise.  If your yaw angle 0.0 represents south, you have to make it -Pi/2 before doing cos/sin or result will be shifted.  Also, you seem to go clock-wise, so you have to multiply the angle by -1 to make it counter-clockwise before calculation.

Comment: Wait, so 360° is different than pi/2 and such? That is probably the problem, so how do I convert the degrees to the pi degrees, so to speak?

Comment: You have to use radians.  Just use Math.toRadians(degrees).  E.g. Math.toRadians(360.0)

Comment: That appears to have done it! Thank you very much for helping out! All I was left with to do was to fix the pitch, because it was backwards for some reason.

Comment: Oh, wait, now when I look down, the camera moves backwards.. I'll try and fix this one myself, and again, thanks for helping me.

Comment: Yeah, i think you have to multiply all angles with -1.0, because you are representing them in the opposite way as trigonometric functions do^^  Always glad to help ;)

Comment: Okay, now I'm starting to see why so many games use the spacebar for flying up and the shift button for flying down.. It's very hard to get the pitch to cooperate with the x and z axes.nI'm just going to do like you said and let xzlength = k(distance). Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Lake, sorry to bother you once more, but in radians, how do you take a value and turn it 90 degrees to the left or right? I'm trying to make it so that pressing left will make the camera move left, and right for right. Here's what I have to make the camera move forwards, and it works: 

double yaw = Math.toRadians((this.getRender3D().getYaw() / 100) * 360);
XZ[0] = -(xzLength * Math.cos(yaw));
XZ[1] = -(xzLength * Math.sin(yaw));

Comment: Well, you can add or subtract 90 before calling toRadians, OR afterward you can add or subtract Pi/2 (3.1439/2).  Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thanks, and based on what you told me, 90 in degrees is equivalent to PI/2? If that's so, I can use that to make my life much easier in many situations. Thanks again!